# how to scroll a div in the ionic app page view?

Tags: html, cordova, ionic-framework, overflow

I use the ionic + cordova to develop an app. 
A whole page in the app can be scrolled, but a div inside the page can not be scrolled on the mobile phone screen with touch gesture, even though I have written the CSS as:

```
ul.doughnut-legend{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: -10px;
  width: 130px;
  height: 150px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}
```

[I want the following legend div can be scrolled on the  mobile devices](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lLxWr.png)

Can any body help please?

Comment: Have you given the ion-scroll directive a try? http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/ionScroll/  You actually just have to wrap this directive around your legends-div.

Answer (score 0):

As [Blauharley suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34463486/how-to-scroll-a-div-in-the-ionic-app-page-view#comment56673094_34463486), you can do it using [`ion-scroll`](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/ionScroll/) directive.

You should wrap your `.doughnut-legend` element in a `ion-scroll`:

```
<ion-scroll zooming="true" direction="xy" style="width: 500px; height: 500px">
  <div class="legends" style="width: 5000px; height: 5000px;">
    <ul class="doughnut-legend">
    </ul>
  </div>
</ion-scroll>
```

Comment: I am also doing what the OP is doing.  I can get my div to scroll - but barely.  As I scroll the div it scrolls slowly, and the whole page still scrolls,...as I scroll my finger up the screen trying to get to the content further down in the div then the whole page - and the div - scroll up off the top and I can no longer see/focus on the div.  How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: Hi @rolinger. Maybe it could be better to create a brand new question for your issue.

Comment: I did...heres the link to it:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66605847/ionic-scroll-div-inside-of-scrolling-page